# C - Al eliminar un elemento de un arreglo reemplazarlo con 0 y más

Tags: c, array

mi problema es que al eliminar o insertar un numero en el arreglo, se repiten, el mismo u otros, y no estoy entendiendo el por que de este error. Aquí les dejo el código para que lo puedan probar y ver el problema del que les hablo.

Mi idea era que al eliminar un numero lo reemplace por 0, o sea que deje vacio ese lugar del arreglo. Muchas gracias!

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #define arr 10

    void Insertar (int vec[], int n, int x);
    void Eliminar (int vec[], int n);
    int buscar (int vec[], int n, int num);
    void Ordenar (int vec[]);

    int main() {

    int vec[arr]; 
    int x,op, n, res;

    for(x=0; x<arr; x++) {

        printf("Ingresa el contenido del vector Nº %d \n", x+1);
        scanf("%d",&vec[x]);


    }

    printf("El vector es: \n");

    for(x=0; x<10; x++) {

        printf("- %d ", vec[x] );
    }

    do {

    printf("\n");

    printf("Ahora ¿que quiere hacer con el vector? \n");

    printf("\n");

    printf("1- Insertar \n");
    printf("2- Eliminar \n");
    printf("3- Buscar \n");
    printf("4- Ordenar \n");
    printf("5- SALIR \n");

    scanf("%d", &op);


    switch(op) {

    case 1: Insertar (vec, n, x); break;
    case 2: Eliminar (vec, n); break;
    case 3: 
        printf("\n Ingrese el elemento a buscar: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        res=buscar(vec, n, x);

        if(res==-1)
            printf("\n El elemento no existe en el arreglo\n");
        else 
            printf("\n El elemento %d se encuentra en la ubicacion %d\n", x, res);
        break;

    case 4: Ordenar(vec);break;
    case 5: printf("Saliendo...\n");break;
    default: printf("ERROR\n");
    }

    } while(op!=5);


    return 0;
}


void Insertar (int vec[], int n, int x) {
    int i, pos, elem;

        printf("Ingrese la posicion donde desee insertar el elemento:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &pos);
        if(pos>arr)
            printf("ERROR\n");
        else{

        printf("Ingrese el valor a insertar: \n");
        scanf("%d", &elem);


        for(i=arr-1; i>=pos-1; i--) {
        vec[i+1] = vec[i];
        vec[pos-1]= elem;

    }
        }
        printf("El arreglo final es: \n");
        for(x=0; x<arr;x++) {
            printf("%d\n", vec[x]);
        }
}

void Eliminar (int vec[], int n) {

    int x, posit;

    printf("Ingrese la posicion donde se encuentre el elemento a eliminar: \n");
    scanf("%d", &posit);

    if(posit>=arr+1)
        printf("Imposible eliminar un elemento que no existe\n");
    else {

        for(x=posit-1; x<arr-1; x++) {

        vec[x]= vec[x+1];

        }
    }
    printf("El arreglo final es: \n");
    for(x=0; x<=arr;x++) {
        printf("%d\n", vec[x]);
    }


}

int buscar (int vec[], int n, int x) {

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if (x==vec[i])
            return i;
    }
}


void Ordenar (int vec[]) {
    int i, t;
    for(i=1; i<=arr-1;i++) {

        while( i>0 && vec[i]<vec[i-1]) {
            t= vec[i];
            vec[i]=vec[i-1];
            vec[i-1]=t;
            i--;

        }

    }
    printf("El arreglo ordenado es: \n");

    for(i=0; i<= arr-1;i++) {
        printf("%d\n", vec[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error en insertar está en a línea `vec[pos] = elem;`, a parte de que no es necesario que esté en un ciclo, debería ser `vec[pos-1] = elem;`, ya que el usuario visualiza los índices desde el 1, no desde el 0. Entonces sí el usuario te dice que ingreses en la posición 3, en realidad tú vas a insertar en el índice 2 de tu arreglo.

```
void Insertar (int vec[], int n, int x)
{
    int i, pos, elem;

    printf("Ingrese la posicion donde desee insertar el elemento:\n", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &pos);
    if(pos>arr)
        printf("ERROR\n");
    else
    {

        printf("Ingrese el valor a insertar: \n");
        scanf("%d", &elem);


        for(i=arr-1; i>=pos-1; i--)
        {
            vec[i+1] = vec[i];
        }

        vec[pos-1] = elem;
    }
    printf("El arreglo final es: \n");
    for(x=0; x<arr; x++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", vec[x]);
    }
}
```

Lo mismo en Eliminar, en la línea `for(x=0; x<=arr; x++)`, ahí estás iterando una vez de más y por eso te salen más números al final, debería ser `for(x=0; x<arr; x++)`.
Si lo que quieres es reemplazar por 0 nada más, no necesitas el ciclo:

```
for(x=posit-1; x<arr-1; x++)
            {
                vec[x]= vec[x+1];
            }
```

Lo único que tienes que hacer es reemplazar el número de la posición ingresada menos 1 (recuerda lo de los índices) por el 0.

```
void Eliminar (int vec[], int n)
{

    int x, posit;

    printf("Ingrese la posicion donde se encuentre el elemento a eliminar: \n");
    scanf("%d", &posit);

    if(posit>=arr+1)
        printf("Imposible eliminar un elemento que no existe\n");
    else
    {
        vec[posit-1] = 0;
    }
    printf("El arreglo final es: \n");
    for(x=0; x<arr; x++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", vec[x]);
    }
}
```